# Managing multiple states inside hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I've recently started to *try* to learn React hooks, but for the life of me I can't figure out some things, like multiple state management, I've found a few example but nothing seems to be in a specific pattern. I'm not even sure how you're supposed to define your states if there's more than 2 and you want to change them individually, should it be like this:

```
const [slides, setSlides] = useState([])
const [currentSlide, setCurrentSlide] = useState(0)
const [tagName, setTagName] = useState([])
```

Or like this:

```
const [states, setStates] = useState({
  slides: [],
  currentSlide: 0,
  tagName: []
})
```

And if both or the second one is viable (honestly I would prefer the second one since its less repetitive in calling useState and closer to the standard state meta) how could one go about changing states in such a example? I couldn't really find anything on this, so what I tried was this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  Object.entries(Slides).forEach(slide => {
   setStates(prevState => ({ slides: [...prevState.slides, slide[1]] }))
  })

}, [])
```

And I messed around with it a bunch trying to get some decent results but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong? And on which one of these to methods of best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: A link to something, a idea, anything is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: you only want to update slides array or each key of state?

Comment: just slides this time, if I have a state setup like the second one where all the states are inside one `const [states, setStates]`, is there a way to update just `slides` or just `currentSlide` or just `tagName` individually without changing anything else? Just like the normal state meta where you copy everything inside state and then _add values to one of the props_ (prop in this case being for example slides)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of updating state, first template is much easy and simple, because each stateUpdate function will be responsible for updating single value, that can be `obj/array/int/bool/string`. Another thing is, to access each value of the state (it will be an object), you need to write `states.slides`, `states.tagName` etc.

With first case, state update will be simply:

```
// only value in case of int/string/bool
updateState({ [key]: value }) or updateState(value);
```

But in second case, state will be an object with multiple keys, so to update any single value you need to copy the object, then pass the updated key-value. Like this:

```
updateState({
  ...obj,
  [key]: newValue
})
```

---

To update the slides array:

```
updateState(prevState => ({
  ...prevState,
  slides: newArray
}))
```

**Handling complex state update:**

Use [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) to handle the complex state update, write a separate reducer function with action types and for each action type so the calculation and return the new state.

For Example:

```
const initialState = { slides: [], tagName: [], currentSlide: 0 };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SLIDES':
      return { ... };
    case 'TAGNAME':
      return { ... };
    case 'CURRENT_SLIDE':
      return { ... }
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

function Counter({initialState}) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  ....
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice you've updated your answer, I think this addition makes the answer the best since it covers all methods, presents useReducer which seems to be designed specifically for handling complex logic and so one. And I did say that I'm interested in the 'by the book' way of doing it too, so I'm going to accept this answer. Even though I'm still a bit confused in regards to for example: `case 'SLIDES':  return { ... }` - in this specific case, we would `return { slide[1] }` or well, anything that we need to be **added** to the _past_ values? it also copies `prevState`?

Comment: no, we need to return the full obj here also like: `return { ...state, [key]: value }` you dont need to worry about the prevState that will be handled by reducer itself.

Comment: Also, just to continue the spread of information, I've tried to use this method `setStates(prevState => ({ ...prevState.states, slides: slide[1] // coming from a forEach }))` but it does not behave as expected _(doesn't copy the object and it doesn't add all the functions)_. So what I did was, I removed the prevState: `setState({ ...states, slides: slide[1] // again, coming from a forEach that goes though a object })` and this worked almost perfectly, only problem is that I don't get each item added to slides, I only get the last one! Any ideas for this?

Comment: its because each time you are just storing only one item in `slides` array, so what you need to do is, prepare the array first (whole array with updated items), then assign the array to `slides: newUpdatedArray`, also do the setState outside of loop, in loop just prepare the newArray. We only need to use `setState` once at the end of all calculation.

Comment: One more question about the reducer please, in this case, where you'd be using a forEach to pull the items that need to be inserted one by one inside the `slides` array that's inside the `states` obj, where exactly would you be calling the forEach to 'push' said items inside the `array`? I think, this is probably the most complicated scenario.

Comment: sure, happy to answer all the questions, in case of without reducer you can so that in setState update function (use block body of arrow function instead of concise), like this: `setStates(prevState => { /*run the loop here and return obj*/ return { .... } })`, and in case of reducer do that in specific action type, then return the final obj.

Comment: Alright I don't think there's anything to add anymore, I'll admit, a lot of these kind of goes over my head for more, but I asked more so that everything is as complete as possible and in the future if anybody else is dealing with these things, they can find some comfort here :)

That being said, I cant wait to start experimenting with all of this to understand better understand and to find a solution that best fits!

Thanks again and happy coding!

Comment: You are a wonderful human being and I wish you all the best :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is true that the `useState` hook can become quite verbose when dealing with complex state object.
In this case, you can also consider using the [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) hook.

I would recommend the reading of [this article](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-usereducer-vs-usestate) about `useState` vs `useReducer`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You are completely correct, I did however find that its best to first accept the answer where all the bases are covered because I'm not the only person that will be using this information in the future:)

Again, thank you very much for the contribution!